# Django select choices with optgroup fails to validate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a a form in Django with two inline forms. One of them is giving me grief.
My model is like so.

```
class BookingActivity(models.Model):
    booking = models.ForeignKey('Booking')
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, choices=programs_as_optgroups())
```

the `activity` ForeignKey choices are generated via this method:

```
def programs_as_optgroups():
    activities = []
    programs = []
    for program in Program.objects.all():
        new_program = []
        new_activities = []
        for activity in Activity.objects.filter(program=program):
            new_activities.append([activity.id, activity.name])

        new_program = [program.name, new_activities]
        activities.append(new_program)

    return activities
```

I'm trying to add `<optgroup>` tags to my `ForeignKey` select which is working. But when I submit the form I get an error: `Cannot assign "u'3'": "BookingActivity.activity" must be a "Activity" instance.`

This makes some sense - sort of. But if I check the `request` data sent from the form post. With choices either setup or not I get the same values, i.e.

`activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, choices=programs_as_optgroups())`

and

`activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)`

both return the a `u'3'` from the form. But I can't figure out why I get an error only when I'm using the optgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying

http://dealingit.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/django-tip-showing-optgroup-in-a-modelform/

in the blog

```
sub_categories.append([sub_category.id, sub_category.name])
```

you have

```
new_activities.append([activity.id, activity])
```

I think you're assuming you will get an object when it actually is a string you're getting back.

Comment: You guessed right. Though what you are reading would still be correct as `acivity` would only be the title in the select choice via __unicode__ method. I will update my code though.

Comment: @sdk900 maybe you should put it in your init method after the super ... To me this looks important.

Comment: Yes that was the problem but because I had stupidly been putting my `__init__` method before my `Meta` class, which I'm assuming because it has the `model` for the form, was overriding the updated field. Though I had tried in the modelForm changing the field like this `activity = forms.ChoiceField(choices=programs_as_optgroups())` which was giving me the same error as above.